# Slick 3.0.0 Delete all Entries From a Table

Tags: sql-delete, slick

The following query:

```
val resultValue = Await.result(db.run(MyTable.myTableItems.delete), 2.seconds)
```

Strangely, the above query when run gives me the max value for the Id that I have in that particular table. Why is that? What is the Slick equivalent of delete all entries from a Table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result from `delete` is the number of rows affected by the delete. If your id starts from 1, it could be a coincidence that the number of rows affected happens to be the same as largest id in the table.

Calling `delete` on a table query is the way to delete all entries from a table. For example, if you have

```
val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
```

...then `coffees.delete` is the action to remove all rows.

Useful link: [Deleting](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/queries.html#deleting), in the Slick Manual.